# How to add a action target to a button which is animated out in UIAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft style?

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, uibutton, action

I have a button which is animated out from (hidden->unhidden) on a uitableViewCell.

there are a imageview and a button at the same rect position In the tableViewCell,When user select one of tableviewcell from tableview, the imageView animate to hidden and the button animate to show.Two of the view(imageView&button) are load from a xib file. I have added a action to the button and link it with a IBAction method.

My Question:when user touch at the button, the action method have not been invoked, Why?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:cell.id context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(focusCellFinished:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell.containerView cache:YES];
cell.imagePhoto.hidden = true;
cell.playButton.hidden = false;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

when user select a button, tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: will be invoked, i don't need that, i just want to invoke the button method.

BTW,I know and try if just add a button normal without animate disappear, it can add a target action and be invoked successfully.

Any answer and comments will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
[UIView beginAnimations:cell.id context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(focusCellFinished:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell.containerView cache:YES];
cell.imagePhoto.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (-100,30);
cell.playButton.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (100,30);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

here change the value of `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation (x,y);` according to your frame position

Comment: hi my friend, thanks for this reply.I am not need to know how to hide a view and display another view, I just want to know why the animated button can't add action.

Comment: Are you animated a button out too?

Comment: Thanks again. It is work normally now. I just write again the Xib file. Maybe it is because the SDK reasons.